# How to do image parallel upload to server using Alamofire or NSUrl swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, multipartform-data, nsurlsession

I want to upload multiple images in parallel to the server using `Alamofire` or `NSUrlSessions` and get responses for all the uploaded images using `MVVM model`

Comment: I also have same issue where I have to upload multiple files i.e If I have 10 images then I have to call same Api for 10 times asynchronously and get the responses for all request.I am also using mvvm pattern

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51738817/2395636) might help.

Comment: @Kamran I have to store the response I have to know to which request i am getting the response.

Comment: Use operation queue and count how many operations are left?

Comment: you can check this link may help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499768/upload-multiple-images-in-swift-using-alamofire)

Comment: @stevenpcurtis can you give some reference link